# AngularJS: Http API Service - any improvements / remarks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular.js, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Could you please review the below AngularJS service. What it does is centralize all (relevant) HTTP action calls.

Do you see any chances for improvement?:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("services.api")
    .factory("apiService", [
        "$http",
        "$q",
        "coreUtilityService",
        "constantsServiceNames",
        "constantsApiRequestFor",
        function (
            $http,
            $q,
            coreUtilityService,
            constantsServiceNames,
            constantsApiRequestFor
            ) {
            // === START SERVICE === //

            var self = {};

            self.Name = constantsServiceNames.ApiService;

            self.ExecuteRequest = function(verb, fullUri, data) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                verb = verb.toLowerCase();

                //start with the uri
                var httpArgs = [fullUri];
                if (verb.match(/post|put/)) {
                    httpArgs.push(data);
                }

                $http[verb].apply(null, httpArgs)
                .success(function (response) {
                    defer.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function (response, status) {
                    defer.reject("HTTP Error: " + status);
                });

                return defer.promise;
            }

            /*
            Do a request to any RESTful receiver. Meant for external use only, use DoViewRequest
            for internal requests.
            */
            self.DoRequest = function (verb, uri, data) {
                var fullUrl = coreUtilityService.GetBaseUrl(constantsApiRequestFor.WebAPI, uri);

                return self.ExecuteRequest(verb, fullUrl, data);
            };

            /*
            This will target an MVC View of the client application. The url will be different.
            */
            self.DoViewRequest = function (verb, uri) {
                var fullUrl = coreUtilityService.GetBaseUrl(constantsApiRequestFor.View, uri);

                return self.ExecuteRequest(verb, fullUrl, null);
            };

            // === PUBLIC === //

            return {
                Get: function (uri) {
                    return self.DoRequest("get", uri);
                },
                Post: function (uri, data) {
                    return self.DoRequest("post", uri, data);
                },
                Put: function (uri, data) {
                    return self.DoRequest("put", uri, data);
                },
                Delete: function (uri) {
                    return self.DoRequest("delete", uri);
                },
                View: function (uri) {
                    return self.DoViewRequest("get", uri);
                }
            }

            // === END SERVICE === //
        }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas - nothing major :

1. Encapsulating the methods in `self` doesn't really add anything. A set of function statements or function expressions would do the job and `self.` could be purged all through.
2. The [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) should be purged.
3. "method" would be better understood than "verb".
4. Does `DoRequest()` not throw when `data` is not passed? Do range checking in `doRequest()` instead of `ExecuteRequest()`.
5. Possibly allow for omitted `uri`, defaulting to empty string (browser will use current page's url). Could be useful in some use cases.
6. By convention Initial-caps are reserved for constructors. Change to lower-case all through.
7. Possibly use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) in the exposer. (Check that browser compatibility is acceptable).

```
angular.module("services.api").factory("apiService", [
"$http",
"$q",
"coreUtilityService",
"constantsServiceNames",
"constantsApiRequestFor",
function (
    $http,
    $q,
    coreUtilityService,
    constantsServiceNames,
    constantsApiRequestFor
) {
    // === START SERVICE === //
    // var name = constantsServiceNames.ApiService; // necessary?
    var executeRequest = function(method, fullUri, data) {
        method = method.toLowerCase();
        var httpArgs = [fullUri];
        if (data) {
            httpArgs.push(data);
        }
        return $http[method].apply(null, httpArgs).then(null, function (response) {
            throw new Error("HTTP Error: " + response.status);
        });
    };
    /*
    Do a request to any RESTful receiver. Meant for external use only, use DoViewRequest
    for internal requests.
    */
    var doRequest = function (method, uri, data) {
        uri = uri || '';
        data = (!data || !method.match(/post|put/)) ? null : data; // or similar
        return ExecuteRequest(method, coreUtilityService.GetBaseUrl(constantsApiRequestFor.WebAPI, uri), data);
    };
    /*
    This will target an MVC View of the client application. The url will be different.
    */
    var doViewRequest = function (method, uri) {
        uri = uri || '';
        var fullUrl = coreUtilityService.GetBaseUrl(constantsApiRequestFor.View, uri);
        return ExecuteRequest(method, fullUrl, null);
    };
    // === PUBLIC === //
    return {
        'get':    doRequest.bind(null, 'get'),
        'post':   doRequest.bind(null, 'post'),
        'put':    doRequest.bind(null, 'put'),
        'delete': doRequest.bind(null, 'delete'),
        'view':   doViewRequest.bind(null, 'get')
    };
    // === END SERVICE === //
}]);
```

Comment: All very good points, thanks! A question with point 7, shouldn't there be a data parameter in the `bind()`  for post/put?

Comment: Bind statements often look wrong. I've used them quite a bit and still have to concentrate. The thing to remember is that `.bind()` is not a call but something that returns a function. Here, a `null` context is provided (doRequest() and doViewRequest() don't use `this` therefore don't need a context), and "get" etc are "bound-into" the returned function as its *first* param. Further param(s) are passed when the returned function is eventually called for real, and don't need to appear in these `.bind()` statements.

Comment: I'll look into it when able, thanks for the information!

Comment: Minor side note regarding 6: I'm not a fan of lowerCamelCase for functions/methods, because that makes callbacks confusing. Hard to see if you're passing a variable or function. I prefer the .net naming rules.